# Printing object[].value in C#

Tags: c#, class, object

Im working on a project and Im new to c#.
So, I have to pass some values from a file into an Object and I want to check if they are passed correctly by printing them, but can't find a way how.
I have a class **Hotel** where i want to put the values

```
public class Hotel
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    int stars { get; set; }
    int numberOfRooms { get; set; }
    public Hotel(int Id, string Name, int Stars, int NumberOfRooms)
    {
        id = Id;
        name = Name;
        stars = Stars;
        numberOfRooms = NumberOfRooms;
    }
}
```

And the **Running** class with Main where everything is done

```
    public class Running
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hotel[] hotel = new Hotel[0];
            hotel = new Hotel[3];
            int Id = 0;
            string Name = "";
            int Stars = 0;
            int NumberOfRooms = 0;
            //...
            //code for reading file and passing the values into Id, Name, Stars, NumberOfRooms
            hotel[0] = new Hotel(Id, Name, Stars, NumberOfRooms);
        }
    }
```

I tried for example the `Console.WriteLine(hotel[0].name);` and other "combinations" but got compilation error. Only the `Console.WriteLine(hotel);` seemed to print "`Project.Hotel`".I would appreciate it if anyone could help or advise. Also, Im really sorry if I mispronounced anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. `name` is a private property of `Hotel`, which is likely the error message you get when you tried `Console.WriteLine(hotel[0].name);`. It is highly likely you want to make these properties public. Please consider posting the error message the compiler gives you in future questions as this makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: You can override `ToString` to get a better output for `Console.WriteLine(hotel)`.  `hotel[0].name` doesn't work because `name` is private (the default).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks a lot for the notice, it was indeed the error, and for the advice!!

Comment: @juharr I will check that thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that the properties of your class are not publicly visible, they're private by default. To have them accessible from outside of the class set them to public! Like this:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int stars { get; set; }
public int numberOfRooms { get; set; }
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

P.S. these lines of your code are kind of pointless:

```
Hotel[] hotel = new Hotel[0];
hotel = new Hotel[3];
```

Try replacing them with this:

```
Hotel[] hotel = new Hotel[3];
```

Basically what you were doing is making an array of hotels of size 0 (why would you ever want that?), then replacing that array with a new array of size 3. The new code I provided just creates an array of size 3 the first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! The compilation error was fixed, but the output was blank. In advance, i printed the 'Name' itself `Console.WriteLine(Name);` to check if it was blank aswell but it was correct.. If you could spot anything wrong in the code i put, it would be really helpfull. If not, it's ok you 've done your part to help

Comment: @PeterS Glad to be of help bud. If you could mark this as the answer to let others know this solved your problem that'd be great! As to your name being blank issue, I think this comes down to an issue with reading in and parsing the info from your file. But you've left that as a comment so I can't tell for sure. If you provide it I could better help you.

Comment: Did you check the value of `Name` _after_ reading data from file? One reason I could think of is when you're reading your data from the file you somehow overwrite the variable.

Comment: @CapnJack Thanks a lot again for trying to help, noticed the edited part, and @Sach yes i did check the value after reading data and not changing it.. And actually found the problem was in hotel[], it should be `Console.WriteLine(hotel[1].name);` ....silly me. Thanks for your interest!